# Unable to call bootstrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I followed a YouTube tutorial (on modals) exactly but nothing appears in my browser. Isit due to my script/link? Some help please.

Here are my codes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>Modal example</title>

        <link href="bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="modal" id="myModal" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1>hi</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="span4" /> <br />
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="span4" /> <br /><br />
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Login</button>

                </form>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is correct, however you require a way to show the modal on your page since the modal itself has aria-hidden="true". You can do this in JavaScript by calling .modal("show")/.modal("hide") with jQuery or by using a link with its data-target set to your modal's id value.

I have included the link you could use to open the HTML as an example. Insert the link immediately below the body tag in your example.

`<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</a>`

data-toggle="modal" & data-target="#myModal" are telling bootstrap that you want this link to toggle the modal with an ID of 'myModal'.

edit: Also, Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. I would recomend changing the script tags and link tags to the following to use the recomended CDN for Bootstrap & jQuery to simplify your setup. If you do not use the CDN, you will need to download the files and include them with their proper path in your  section.

`<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>`

`<link rel="stylesheet" ref="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">`

`<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: hey appreciate the reply. i placed that line of code directly under my body tag. now as i open my html it shows the words "Open modal" but as i clicked on it, the modal still does not appear :/

Comment: I apologize for this taking so long to come to mind, but Bootstrap's JavaScript components require jQuery as well. Include these script tags prior to the inclusion of the bootstrap files in your <head></head> tags.

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

I have edited the original answer to include this as well. Cheers!

Comment: awesome! i would highly suggest reading bootstraps examples too as they detail which effects can be applied to their JavaScript components. Also, if you can mark this as the answer that would be awesome. Happy Coding!

(bootstrap documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples)

Comment: amateur coder here.. its for my sch assignment. yes will read up more on it. need more than just this basic. And rly thanks again ^^

Answer (score 0):

first you should go to this site "http://getbootstrap.com/"
then click the download button in the center of screen.then extract the zip file and copy them to your project file. *** the IMPORTANT point ***
copy this code against your HTML code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/bootstrap.min.css' >
<body>

</body>
    <script src='js/bootstrap.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
</html>
```